# Best practices for "connecting" two separate react apps

Tags: reactjs, npm

Lets say we have two react apps. And we want to connect them. By "connect" I mean passing data from one to the other.

One option would be to export the `Main` component of the 2nd app and include it as a submodule and then import it in the 1st app and define our router like

```
import SecondApp from 'secondApp';
    ...
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <Router history={ appHistory }>
            <Route path='/' component={ FirstApp } />
            <Route data={ someData } path='/pathb' component={ SecondApp } />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
```

Another option will be to not have it as a submodule but deploy it separately (so it will make the deployments easier) and require the data from the server.

Another option will be to deploy it separately but pass the data through the localStorage.

Probably there more options, but **which are the best practices (if any) and why**?

Comment: So you mean by having each of their stores listen for state changes and react accordingly? Something like `thunk`?

Comment: @OliverQueen the apps will definitely have separate stores. But the initial state of the 2nd app's store will be passed as property from the 1st app. You could in the ideal scenario even run them separately by providing mock data to the second app.

Comment: Are you using redux?

Comment: @OliverQueen One app could be written using redux the other could be written using a store implementation using RX's subject or any other library. It doesnt matter. This is not the question.

Comment: It does have to do with the question. It's helpful knowing how your app manages/handles state changes.

Comment: @OliverQueen the question is not implementation specific, it is about best practices.

Comment: Theoretically, you could use something like this to pass down state like you do properties http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#spread-attributes

Comment: @OliverQueen that's what `data={ someData }` in my code is doing, I am not asking how to do it, I am asking what is the **best practices**

Comment: I'd posit that the correct solution is more dependent on your application setup than library standards. Does it make sense for for apps to share the same store? If not, use the server as the data middleman.

Comment: @lux the 2nd app will use part of the store of the 1st one. But I see your point.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis Well there ya go :-) And this type of reducer composition is a heavily used pattern in Redux, so full steam ahead